# What is the ratio in this pulley system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image: pulley]

This is not a common pulley system. What is the actual ratio for this type?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1:1

The string has a constant tension $N$. The strength pulling the weight is $2N$ (there is left and right part of the string). On the other hand, the strength pulling to the left is also to $N$ (you pull top and bottom string).